# catkin_make test not running my tests

Tags: ros, catkin, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use unit tests in ROS for the first time, using gtest.

The binary for my tests is getting built properly in catkin_ws/devel/lib/project_name/project_name_tests.  I can run it directly from the command line and see useful test run output.

However, I can't figure out how to run it in catkin, which would be more convenient. When I run `catkin_make test` is seems that ctest runs some other tests:

```
Running tests...
Test project /home/awagner/catkin_ws/build
    Start 1: _ctest_project_name_msgs_roslaunch-check_launch
1/2 Test #1: _ctest_project_name_msgs_roslaunch-check_launch ...***Failed    2.02 sec
    Start 2: _ctest_project_name_gtest_project_name_tests
2/2 Test #2: _ctest_project_name_gtest_project_name_tests .......***Failed    0.05 sec

0% tests passed, 2 tests failed out of 2

Total Test time (real) =   2.07 sec

The following tests FAILED:
      1 - _ctest_project_name_msgs_roslaunch-check_launch (Failed)
      2 - _ctest_project_name_gtest_project_name_tests (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
```

Here's how I'm declarng my tests in CMakeLists.txt:

```
if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  catkin_add_gtest(project_name_tests src/tests.cpp)
endif()
```

What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219983/catkin_make-test-not-running-my-tests/) by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2015-10-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on 2022-11-02**:
I had a similar issue when using `catkin_tools`, which was solved by updating the `python3-catkin-tools` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the answer to this earlier question:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/54051/how-do-i-run-unit-tests-for-a-catkin-package/

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2